# Условия для обработки входных данных

Tags: java, строки, ввод

Допустим, есть обьект, для создания которого нужно получить от пользователя некоторые данные (имя, возраст и т.п.). Очевидно, что до создания объекта необходимо убедиться, что все данные корректны (нет пустых строк, числа в правильном диапазоне и т.д.).

Так вот, у меня пока получается писать что-то монструозное типа:

```
if(name != null && !name.isEmpty() && age > 10 && age < 100 &&  (symbol == 'x' || symbol == 'o')) {
    //создание объекта
}
```

Можно сделать методы для проверки и сократить:

```
if(isNameValid() && isAgeValid() && isSymbolValid()) {
    //создание объекта
}
```

Но все равно длинно выходит, потому что здесь всего 3 параметра, а на самом деле может быть больше.

1. Так как правильно обрабатывать данные ситуации?
2. И еще такой момент, что если пользователь ввел правильно 5/6 данных, то необходимо не с начала спрашивать, а переспросить только то, где ошибка. Как такое обрабатывать? Хранить в массиве результаты валид-методов? И потом выбирать из массива те, что неправильны и по ним спрашивать или есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Java есть довольно-таки полезный механизм исключений, который может Вам в этом помочь:

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class TestMain {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final char symbol;

    public TestMain(String name, int age, char symbol) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        checkData();
    }

    private void checkData() {
        StringJoiner errors = new StringJoiner("\n");

        if (name == null || name.isEmpty())
            errors.add("Имя не удовлетворяет условиям: " + name);

        if (age < 10 || age > 100)
            errors.add("Возраст не удовлетворяет условиям:" + age);

        if (symbol != 'x' && symbol != 'o')
            errors.add("Символ не удовлетворяет условиям: " + symbol);

        if (errors.length() > 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errors.toString());
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public char getSymbol() { return symbol; }

    ...

}
```

Если же необходимо проверить локальные переменные, то выбирайте один из двух способов:

1) Обрабатывайте все данные в одном методе:

```
private boolean isDataValid(String name, int age, char symbol) {
    StringJoiner errors = new StringJoiner("\n");

    if (name == null || name.isEmpty())
        errors.add("Имя не удовлетворяет условиям: " + name);

    if (age < 10 || age > 100)
        errors.add("Возраст не удовлетворяет условиям:" + age);

    if (symbol != 'x' && symbol != 'o')
        errors.add("Символ не удовлетворяет условиям: " + symbol);

    if (errors.length() > 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(errors.toString());
    return true;
}
```

2) Выносите проверки каждого параметра в отдельный метод (используйте этот подход для избежания громоздких конструкций в одном методе, помните, что методы должны быть легко читаемыми, а если метод содержит большое количество кода, его читабельность уменьшается):

```
private boolean isDataValid(String name, int age, char symbol) {
    StringJoiner errors = new StringJoiner("\n");

    if (!isNameValid(name))
        errors.add("Имя не удовлетворяет условиям: " + name);

    if (!isAgeValid(age))
        errors.add("Возраст не удовлетворяет условиям:" + age);

    if (!isSymbolValid(symbol))
        errors.add("Символ не удовлетворяет условиям: " + symbol);

    if (errors.length() > 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(errors.toString());
    return true;
}

private boolean isNameValid(String name) {
    return name != null && !name.isEmpty();
}

private boolean isAgeValid(int age) {
    return age >= 10 && age <= 100;
}

private boolean isSymbolValid(char symbol) {
    return symbol == 'x' || symbol == 'o';
}
```

Касательно пункта 2: На практике я бы посоветовал Вам именно его, так как метод должен выполнять только свою работу, он не должен лезть в логику других методов, от которой он, по сути, не зависит.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Удобно. Все я понял что я туплю)) Теперь примерно понятно. Разве что вопрос, что делать если в конструкторе/методе очень много параметров, или это не страшно?

Comment: StringJoiner Только в jdk8, в 7 версии я так понял нету.

Comment: @dimads, StringBuilder есть.

Comment: @dimads Обновил ответ. Да, StringJoiner появился в Java 8, в Java 7 вам придётся использовать StringBuilder, но я бы посоветовал переходить именно на 8 версию, так как многие вещи в ней значительно упростились и код можно писать гораздо более простой и читабельный (особенно в этом помогают стримы). А делать в конструкторе/методе много параметров действительно страшно, ведь чем тоньше метод, тем лучше, об этом я написал в ответе.